# BASH trying to create scrabble word generator, generated error: line 15: ?: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "?")

Tags: bash

This is the script that will run if there are any "?" characters in the command line argument of the main script.  I'm using i to run through the alphabet and essentially setting each "?" to $i for each letter in the alphabet.  I think that the error is occurring because a special character is showing up at the end of the character array that can't be compared to "?", but I don't know how to deal with that.  I did use ShellCheck already.

EDIT:  The text file that is generated by the main script includes all permutations (no repeats) of the letters provided in the command line argument with a hard return between each permutation, and I am pretty sure that the hard return character is what is generating the error.  Here is an example of permute.txt

```
at?
a?t
ta?
t?a
?at
?ta
```

And here is the slightly edited script:

```
#reads the text file produced by another script into the array
readarray words < ./permute.txt
#runs through loop 26 times with i as a letter in the alphabet
for i in {a..z}; do
    #runs through every word in the array provided by the text file
    for j in "${words[@]}"; do
        s=$j #sets $j to a variable to mess with
        declare -a a
        word=""
        #splits string s into character array
        while read -n 1 c; do a+=($c); done  <<< "$s"
        #checks array for "?", used as a blank tile and changes that character to $i
        for k in "${a[@]}"; do if [ "$k" = "?" ]; then a[$k]=$i; fi; done
        #puts the array back together into a string
        for ((k=0; k<${#a}; k++)); do echo $word; word=$word${a[$k]}; done
        valid=$(grep -w $word /usr/share/dict/words) #checks for word in dictionary
        #statement that fixes bug where words with apostrophes end up in the output
        if [ ${#valid} -eq ${#i} ]; then
            echo "$valid"
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Add first line of your script to your question.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/, by the way, would catch some obvious bugs here.

Comment: Fix your quoting, check your shebang and invocation method to make sure your shell is *actually* bash (can't use either `#!/bin/sh` or `sh yourscript`), and either switch from `[` to `[[` or switch from `==` to `=` (the POSIX-standardized string comparison operator; bash adds `==` as an extension, but using it with the POSIX test operator `[ ]` is bad form).

Comment: ...but anyhow, adding all the missing quotes -- as per shellcheck's direction -- will mean that characters with special meaning, or found in IFS, will no longer mess up your code.

Comment: (also, there's no point to a `declare -a` before a `readarray`; the latter implicitly makes the type an array)

Comment: adding an example of the `permute.txt` could help... but this isn't really inline with the [mcve] anyway,

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I changed everything that you suggested, but I still get the same error.  The text file that is generated by the main script includes all permutations (no repeats) of the letters provided in the command line argument with a hard return between each permutation, and I am pretty sure that the hard return character is what is generating the error.  Are there ways to get rid of that?

Comment: I also added an example of permute.txt in the OP.

Comment: How do you start your "bash" script?

Comment: ./blankTile.sh.  The professor explicitly told us to not put #!/bin/sh in the file.  I don't know why, but I'm just following his instructions.

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` would, indeed, be wrong; it needs to be `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or similar for bash.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand rigth, that you want wo replace the ? in the permutations with all characters a..z and then check if they are in the dictionary?
I would try without manually array work and let sed work for you (replacement of ?).

```
for i in {a..z}; do
    for word in $(sed  "s/\?/$i/" permute.txt); do
            grep -w $word /usr/share/dict/words
    done
done
```

You could even use bash's built in replacement in variables:

```
for i in {a..z}; do
    for word in $(< permute.txt); do
        grep -w ${word/\?/$i} /usr/share/dict/words
    done
done
```

btw: I don't understand the last if statement. Since $i is a single character and $valid is a whole line, that at least contains a (in the example) 3-character word, if [ ${#valid} -eq ${#i} ] will never be true.

Comment: As written, both of these would behave badly in several situations. For instance, look at what happens if you have `*` as a word in your input -- the glob gets expanded, meaning that you end up looking for filenames. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for best practices around reading from files.